# how to feed two uiOutput to renderUI within tabs

Tags: r, shiny

When I try to feed to `uiOutput` to `renderUI` while using `tabPanel` in shiny I get an error in the first run. After switching tabs, the app runs ok.

Here is a minimal example that reproduces the error

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Data", 
                 uiOutput("moreControls") 
        ),
        tabPanel("Research",
                 uiOutput("moreControls2") 
        )
    ),
    plotOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$moreControls <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            sliderInput("mean", "Mean", -10, 10, 1),
            textInput("label", "Label")
        )
    })

    output$moreControls2 <- renderUI({
        tagList(
            sliderInput("sd", "SD", 1, 50, 10),
            textInput("label2", "Label2")
        )
    })

    output$plot1 <- renderPlot({      
        hist(rnorm(n = 100,input$mean, input$sd) , xlim = c(-100, 100) )
    })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Vivek's answer is nice but here is another way:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("mean", "Mean", -10, 10, 1),
      textInput("label", "Label")
    )
  })

  output$moreControls2 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("sd", "SD", 1, 50, 10),
      textInput("label2", "Label2")
    )
  })
  outputOptions(output, "moreControls2", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ 
    req(input$mean, input$sd)
    hist(rnorm(n = 100, input$mean, input$sd) , xlim = c(-100, 100) )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The `input$mean` is not available before the `uiOutput` renders, and `input$sd` too, but in addition `input$sd` is not available until you switch to the second tab, because the sliderInput is hidden.

Comment: Thank you so much (to both!)

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because Shiny hasn't evaluated those values when your app runs. As such, the input values aren't actually available to `renderPlot()`

A good way to pass in values for the plot would be to use a reactive expression. In the code below I have used `plot_params()` and inside the reactive, I make a list which stores the parameters of producing your plot.

I'd also recommend using `shiny::validate()` to ensure that the input values are valid before rendering output. (See use below)

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Data", 
             uiOutput("moreControls") 
    ),
    tabPanel("Research",
             uiOutput("moreControls2") 
    )
  ),
  plotOutput("plot1")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$moreControls <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("mean", "Mean", -10, 10, 1),
      textInput("label", "Label")
    )
  })

  output$moreControls2 <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      sliderInput("sd", "SD", 1, 50, 10),
      textInput("label2", "Label2")
    )
  })

  # Reactive expression for plot parameters.
  plot_params <- reactive({
    list(
      mean = input$mean,
      sd = input$sd
    )
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$mean, 'Please check that mean is set!'),
      need(input$sd, 'Please check that sd is set.')
    )
    hist(rnorm(n = 100, plot_params()$mean, plot_params()$sd) , xlim = c(-100, 100) )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```